# How can I solve this error to plot those two plot side by side?

Tags: julia

I have tried this code to plot these two side by side.

**Edited**

```
using StatsBase, Plots
    using Distributions
    n= 21600
    P = M = Vector{Int}(undef,n)
    P[1] =100 
    for second in 2:n
      toss = sample(["H","T"], Weights([0.5,0.5]))
      M[second] = rand(Poisson(5),1)
      if toss=="H" 
          P[second]=P[second-1]+M[second]
      else
          P[second]=P[second-1]-M[second]
      end
    end
    
    plot1((P))
    hline!([0])
    
    plot2((P))
    hline!([0])
    
    plot(plot1, plot2, layout = (1, 2), legend = false)
```

This is my code. Getting error as

```
ArgumentError: invalid index: sec of type typeof(sec)
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to have mixed up sec and second in your loop. `sec` is also a function name [https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/math/#Base.Math.sec-Tuple{Number}](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/math/#Base.Math.sec-Tuple%7BNumber%7D). Replace each instance of `sec` with `second`

```
using StatsBase, Plots, Distributions
n= 21600
P = Vector{Int}(undef,n)
M = similar(P) #unless you want P and M to point to the same location in memory
# could also do P,M  = Vector{Int}(undef,n),Vector{Int}(undef,n)
P[1] =100 
M[1] =100 
for second in 2:n
   toss = sample(["H","T"], Weights([0.5,0.5]))
   M[second] = rand(Poisson(5)) #puting rand(Poisson(5),1) gives a vector of length 1
   if toss=="H" 
       P[second]=P[second-1]+M[second]
   else
       P[second]=P[second-1]-M[second]
   end
end
    
plot1 = plot(P)
hline!([0])    
plot2 = plot(M)
hline!([0])
    
plot(plot1, plot2, layout = (1, 2), legend = false)
```

Comment: Now getting 'MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Vector{Int64} to an object of type Int64'

Comment: rand(Poisson(),1) returns a vector of length 1. I will edit my answer to give working code.

Comment: Works fine! Big  help :)

Comment: Great! I'm glad.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246552/discussion-between-xyz-and-arthur-newbury).